# Excel ignoring comma when using PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data from an external database program (Simcorp dimension) into Excel.

When I copy the external data into Excel using ctrl c/v no issues arise.

When I run VBA code to paste from my clipboard, the number "1,000000000" (from the external database) gets parsed as "1000000000" (in Excel).

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A5").PasteSpecial "Text"
    End With
End Sub
```

I tried to set the decimaldelimiter as "," etc. and no result. Also, I believe that my only choices for PasteSpecial are "Text" and "Unicode Text" and tried them both.

Comment: please show the `Copy` part

Comment: After your VBA does the `Copy` and before you allow Excel to do the `Paste`, try to paste into a normal notepad to see what is currently held in the clipboard. If Excel managed to copy the text with the comma, then you can try to force it to paste it. But if Excel never saw a comma when copying, then no matter how hard you try to paste, it would not yield something it never had.

Comment: I've not seen "Text" as an argument for the `Range.PasteSpecial` method. And if I use it here, I get a `Type Mismatch` error.  Can you show more of your code? Or can someone explain why that line is valid?

Comment: @HTH, The copy part is just from the external database. I am just selecting some cells from that program and ctrl c.

Comment: @Ahmad What do you mean paste into a normal notepad? If I ctrl+c the data and open a notepad I paste the correct data, i.e. "1,00000000" and not "1000000000". Or can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean: let Excel do the copy, but you do the paste to see if the clipboard has the comma or not. Maybe the copying done by excel is a bit different than the one done by you from the keyboard

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I believe that this only works when you are copying data from third party programs. Then, the usual PasteSpecial properties are not there i.e.  values/formulas/format etc. (at least in my case)

Comment: @Ahmad Ah okey. I'll try :)

Comment: Ah, it's not a parameter for the `Range.PasteSpecial` method.  It is a parameter for the `Worksheet.PasteSpecial` method.

Comment: What does the `,` mean in your source data?  Eg is it a decimal separator and the value is `1` with a lot of trailing `0`'s?  Or is it a string that has no numerical meaning?

Comment: @chrisneilsen sorry, yes it is a decimal separator and the value is 1 with a lot of trailing zeros...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try formatting the cell as text before doing the paste:

```
Sub CopyPaste()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A5")
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .PasteSpecial "Text"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! That solved the problem! Huge Thanks!!